# Oneliner for testing std::vector contents

Tags: c++, boost, tdd, googletest, c++98

What is a more convenient way of doing this:

```
EXPECT_EQ(mock->params.size(), 2);
EXPECT_EQ(mock->params[0], "firstCall");
EXPECT_EQ(mock->params[1], "secondCall");
```

One problem with the above is that the test cases will crash when doing test driven development where the size of mock->params will first be zero before the actual code under test is written.

BTW, I am not allowed to use GoogleMock since it needs certain compiler flags which I can't use.  I can use std and boost.

Comment: Wouldn't using `ASSERT_EQ` instead of `EXPECT_EQ` work? That would exit the function immediately.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may try to use [Boost.Assign](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/libs/assign/doc/index.html). For instance, [list_of](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/libs/assign/doc/index.html#list_of) sequence can be compared with vector:

[live demo](http://ideone.com/mPzKTS)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ostream>
#include <vector>
#include <boost/assign/list_of.hpp>
using namespace std;
using namespace boost::assign;

int main()
{
    vector<int> v;
    v.push_back(0);
    v.push_back(1);
    cout << (v == list_of(0)(1) ) << endl;
    cout << (v == list_of(1) ) << endl;
    cout << (v == list_of(1)(2) ) << endl;
}
```

Output is:

```
1
0
0
```

Answer (score 0):

Not a one liner but should do what you want:

```
std::vector<std::string> expected;
expected.push_back("firstCall");
expected.push_back("secondCall");
EXPECT_EQ(mock->params,expected);
```

Otherwise I would recommend to use `ASSERT_EQ()` for the first test to prevent your test case from crashing as @Rook states in his comment (that's what it's designed for).

**UPDATE:**
Using Boost Assign as @Evgeny Panasyuk's answer suggests it should look like this:

```
EXPECT_EQ(mock->params,list_of("firstCall")("secondCall"));
```

If I understood this correctly (its not so clear from the answer, and I've personally never used this).

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Google Mock](http://code.google.com/p/googlemock)'s (Google Mock is Google Test's companion mocking framework) rich library of matchers to write clear looking test assertions:

```
#include <gtest.h>
#include <gmock.h>

using testing::ElementsAre;

TEST(Foo, Bar) {
  EXPECT_THAT(mock->params, ElementsAre("firstCall", "secondCall"));
}
```

That assertion also produces clear message when the tested condition is violated.